# Grammar of Self Invoking Anonymous Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

From what I have read from other topics about the issuse SIAFs or Self Invoking Anonymous Functions are simply there to serve as a container, and it limits the scope of variables (from what I have learnt). Now, the question is, why can I do this:

```
$("ul>li").click((function(){

}));
```

But not add another SIAF after it? Like so:

```
$("ul>li").click((function(){

}));

(function(){

});
```

It is weird to me, as this, just the SIAF on its own gives me no errors in the IDE:

```
$("ul>li").click((function(){

}));

(function(){

});
```

Comment: None of the functions in your question are invoked by the code posted. They're just function instantiation expressions.

Comment: None of them are self invoking. You need a `()` or a `.call()` or a `.apply()` at the end for them to be so.

Comment: I've always heard them called IIFEs: "Immediately invoked function expressions". Out of curiosity, where does your terminology come from?

Comment: On further reflection, I don't think a function can actually invoke itself: it must be invoked before it can invoke.

Comment: @waleed Khan: tuts+ thats where i got it from. Namely the instructor was Jeffrey Way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
(function() { .. });
```

is a no-op expression, and in particular it does not involve a function call. A function object is instantiated but it's not used in any way.

This:

```
(function() { ... })();
```

*does* do something, because the trailing `()` causes the function to be invoked.  (It doesn't invoke itself.)

In JavaScript, a reference to a function is just a value, and a function is just an object (well, a special object).  When a reference to a function is followed by a parenthesized list of values, then that's a function call.  It doesn't matter where the reference to the function comes from.  (Where it comes from can affect the semantics of the function call, but not the basic fact of the function call itself.)

*edit* — the terminology "self-invoking function expression" has gained some currency. I won't wade into a dispute, but in my opinion it's less accurate than the alternative "immediately-invoked function expression" because really a function can't invoke itself externally. It can include a call to itself, but that's a different thing entirely. However I understand the spirit of the term and I think it's harmless.

Comment: The **It doesn't invoke itself** part warrants more prominence as the OP has used *self-invoking* many times.

Comment: Thanks for this. Makes perfect sense. Its a bit confusing with all the braces and brackets.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac yes, I agree; it doesn't help that the `function` keyword does double-duty in JavaScript.